# Vw Passat B8 inner taillight replacement

Tags: vw, diesel, tail-lights, passat

I'm trying to replace the inner tail light bulb on the boot of my B8 Passat estate. Is it just a case of removing the 2 screws under the plastic cap in the boot lid? I believe I have the correct bulb which I've been told is the 501 but I just can't seem to figure out how to remove the actual light to replace the bulb

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Using a flashlight (torch) look inside the trunk (boot) in the vicinity of the tail light assembly to find an access panel in the fabric liner. These are usually held in place with Velcro and no tools are required. Just pull the tab if you can find one, and with an awful ripping sound, the tail light socket should be revealed.

Twist the knurled ring counterclockwise (anticlockwise) about 1/3 turn and the socket should release from the assembly. Note that the tabs on the socket that engage with the assembly are unequal and will only reassemble if re-inserted in the original orientation. After replacing bulb, tighten the socket clockwise and replace the access panel.

EDIT: The above applies to the *outer* tail light bulbs and I just realized that you asked about the *inner*. If there is a plastic panel on the inside of the rear hatch directly opposite the inner bulbs, and if it can be removed easily with two screws, this probably serves the same purpose as the Velcro-mounted panel mentioned above.

Comment: I would only mention, with any bulb, do not touch the bulb with bare fingers, as this will transfer oil from the fingertips. Many bulbs are susceptible to this and will die in short order. Best to handle the bulb with a paper towel or by putting some type of clean gloves on. While not all bulbs are susceptible, best practice is to not touch any bulb with bare fingers to remain on the safe side.